# Javascript in javascript IF condtion

Tags: javascript

How can I call another javascript in a condition.    Lets say I have

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
if(condition)
{
< script type="text/javascript" src="">< /script>}
else(condition)
{
< script type="text/javascript" src="">< /script>}
```

Comment: You can't mix HTML and JavaScript like that. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Why are you trying to conditionally load different script files?

Comment: they are ad tags for mobile and desktop view. So i need to call them seperately,

Comment: Did you find something that worked?

Comment: No.. not yet as of now

Comment: Did you try my method I typed out below? It is how https://html5boilerplate.com/ and other starter kits do it... I usually try to do this type of logic with php so it happens before dom is loaded but JS works too.

Comment: can you help me doing tht in PHP?

Comment: are you using php?  <?php echo condition?'<script src="a-sexy-script"></script>':'<script src="some-other-script"></script>'; ?>

Comment: I havnt tried it in PHP yet

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  if(condition) {
    script.src = "one.js";
  } else {
    script.src = "two.js";
  }  
  head.appendChild(script);
  </script>
```

Comment: That might work better than `innerHTML +=` depending on OP's usage for the script.

Comment: innerHTML is not a good use in javascript to add others elements to the DOM.

Comment: Why in the world someone downvoted me ?
Stop this please. Or at least explain the reason for this.

Comment: The logic worked but then because script shows the ads on website, I think its not fetching ads. Any other suggestion?

Comment: What is not fetching the ads ?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.adnetwork.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=386133869"></script> Im using this in 2nd condition but its not showing the ad on website when i use ur logic. I used it like this-- script.src = "http://ad.ladnetwork/show_app_ad.js?section_id=386133869";

Comment: Since the page is blank it makes sense.

Comment: This page ===> http://ad.ladnetwork/show_app_ad.js?section_id=386133869%22 is blank, there's no script or anything else.

Comment: http://ad.leadboltmobile.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=386133869 this is the actual script

Answer (score 1):

How about place something like this in your head:

```
<script>
     if(someCondition){
         document.write(\'<script src="awesome-script-a.js"><\/script>\');
     }
     else{
        document.write(\'<script src="awesome-script-b.js"><\/script>\');
     }


</script>
```

This is how HTML5 Broiler plate and The Roots.io Starter theme handles scripts loaded via CDN.

There is a slight performance hit as document.write writes to an already open page.

See http://javascript.info/tutorial/document-write

Comment: @Wyatt what do yo mean? This is how I alway include my cdn scripts.  I see if they are loaded if not I load the local one.  For example JQuery.  It is common practice.

Comment: @Wyatt I do not think you are correct in my down vote or your comment.  True it does write to an already open loaded page so it takes a slight performance hit.. but what does it override.  See html5 broiler plate and majority of wordpress themes I use.. Especially those developed by Roots.io they all use this method?

Answer (score 0):

[getscript](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) method in jquery lest you Get a script inside your JavaScript code

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = true ? 'source1' : 'source2';
  document.querySelector('head').appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

try using this line, then you can redirect to another page

```
if (p == null) 
{
out.write("<script >window.location.href='index.jsp';</script>");
} else {
out.write("<script >window.location.href='123.jsp';
}
```

Comment: What's `out`? I think you're mixing server-side and client-side code which will not work.